# Querying the database through PHP (some trouble)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay so I'm trying to query the database to find the value in the `name` column that corresponds to the value in the `id` column. So I have the id, and I use that to get the value. For some reason, this does not seem to work. Echoing name doesn't print out the name that corresponds to that id, instead it prints out just `1`, and I don't get any errors either.

```
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'database_name');
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);

    $query = 'SELECT name FROM files 
        WHERE id=' .$id;

    $query_p = $con->prepare($query);

    $name = $query_p->execute();


    $con->close;

echo $name;
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is used when outputting to a web page, not when querying the database.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but looking at the code you've got some fundamental misunderstandings of how mysqli works.  Your best bet is to go back to basics and read up on the API.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php, or if that's not clear enough (I admit that it's not great), try here for a clear example of the steps required: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'database_name');
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM files WHERE id=' . $_GET["id"];
$result = $db->query($sql);
//...
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$name = $row['name'];
```

Comment: What are the .. for? and I for some reason just get a blank page when trying this.

Comment: You do not need a loop to get one row unless there are many names with the same id or there is no row with such id so this code assumes there is one row present.

Comment: Here is the .php file that I am using it in, the header stuff works but after that the video player / div does not load at all.

http://pastebin.com/UPWGFHik

Comment: haha, of course not. You can take a look at my code in the comment above :P

Comment: What about valid host, username, db name and password? Turn on displaying errors...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41513/discussion-between-maaz-and-artur)

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $query_p->execute(); //  This won't give you the name back
```

**execute()** doesn't return you those values.

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Don't you think you have to `fetch` the result?

```
$query_p = $con->prepare($query);
$query_p->execute();
$query_p->bind_result($name);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s \n", $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $id = $_GET["id"];
 $query = 'SELECT name FROM files  WHERE id="'.$id.'"' ;
 $query_p = $con->prepare($query);
 $sth = $query_p->execute();
  while( $row = $sth->fetchAll()){
     echo $row['name'];
 }
```